# TYPO3 uploading progress

Tags: php, typo3

I have TYPO3 version 7.6.18

```
    public function uploadProgressAction(){
        session_start();
        echo $_SESSION['progval'];
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * action create
     *
     * @param \Istar\Fefiles\Domain\Model\Video $newVideo
     */
    public function createAction(\Istar\Fefiles\Domain\Model\Video $newVideo)
    {
        session_start();
        $progress_percents = 0;
        while(1 ==1){
            $progress_percents = $progress_percents + 1;
            $_SESSION['progval'] = $progress_percents;
            session_write_close();
            sleep(0.5);
        }
        die();
}
```

this is my code. I sending ajax requests to uploadProgressAction and I always receive 1. I t seems that session set only one time. Help me please ) where is a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

After calling `session_write_close()`, your session is .. closed and you cannot write to it anymore.